# How do I start/stop my lightsail instance without manually logging into aws console?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to automate a switch between my on-prem server and a lightsail instance. 
The idea is to have a safe-mode. If my on-prem server fails, I will have the lightsail instance run only critical services, while I try to bring up my on-prem server.

So, the step would be as follows -

1. The monitoring tools recognize missed heartbeat from on-prem
2. A script is triggered which starts up the lightsail instance
3. It also triggers a dns flip, which points my domain to lightsail.
4. When on-prem heartbeat is back, the script reverses dns changes and then shuts down lightsail instance.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, sounds possible ... your description is pretty darn close, if not exactly, a high availability setup.

I would suggest you run the monitoring script on your lightsail instance so you don't need a 3rd instance to run the switchover scripts.  You can also keep the lightsail instance synced with your on premises server.

Alternatively, you can use the aws cli to spin up your lightsail instance.  Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/index.html

FWIW: I would suggest looking for a pre-build High Availability (HA) product so you don't have to do the hard work.  Heck, AWS might even offer something of that nature.